# Exception when using Apache POI to read XLSX file

Tags: java, exception, apache-poi, xlsx, xmlbeans

I'm currently working with Apachi, as I needed to read data from a XLSX file, and it will later be converted to CSV. Here's the code I'm using to create my XSSFWorkbook, and it is causing an exception every single time. From what I could find, XMLBeans is part of the cause. It has been deprecated, however, it is a dependency of POI in this instance.

```
public static void appendCSV(File inputFile, String outputFile, String tag)
{
    System.out.println(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
       InputStream inp = null;
        try {
            inp = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inp);
```

My exception gets thrown at the last line in the block above.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:65)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:601)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:174)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:279)
at BigBangarang.appendCSV(BigBangarang.java:68)
at BigBangarang.main(BigBangarang.java:268)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:62)
... 5 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setLoadEntityBytesLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.<clinit>(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:50)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.readFrom(SharedStringsTable.java:127)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.<init>(SharedStringsTable.java:108)
... 11 more
```

Has anybody ran into this situation before? I have the most up to date release of XMLBeans, and I'm almost feeling like I may need to find an older version, as it says a method is missing. I'm not sure if there is an alternate/easier way to either read an XLSX, or to simply convert it to a CSV prior to handling any data.

Comment: What is Apache POI and java version?

Comment: You have a library conflict. If you are using Maven post your pom.xml.

Comment: POI 3.14, Java 7. Below is a screenshot of all referenced libraries, there is a possibility it could be conflicting with some of my previous Apache commons libraries maybe?
http://i.imgur.com/pfojX1H.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either need to upgrade your XMLBeans version to 2.6, or to upgrade you Apache POI version to 3.15 beta 1 or later.

You're hitting [Apache POI bug #59195](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59195), for which a temporary workaround was applied around a month ago, and is included in the 3.15 beta 1 release. (Also in nightly builds from the time of the commit onwards). A full fix will take a bit longer, follow that bug if you're interested!

Comment: When I was looking for XMLBeans, I found 2.4 originally. Is there anything newer than 2.6 that will also work? From what I saw, it was deprecated.

Comment: Apache XMLBeans 2.6 is the newest version available. There's talk of a bugfix 2.6.1 release, no date yet. No new development is happening on xmlbeans, only on projects using it!